# Is there any isset-like function in JSP?

Tags: jsp, variables, undefined

I was wondering if we could check for all `undefined` and `null` variables in JSP using its built-in functions?

I know I can build a function to do that, but I need a lazy solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<c:if test="${name == null}">variable name is undefined</c:if>
```

For testing you can define and undefine a variable using:

```
<c:set var="name" value="Petra"/>
<c:set var="name" value="${null}"/>
```

To state you are using the core JSTL tags add this to the top of the page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
```

Comment: Real Problem is:  on posting data through forms. Wanted to check null and "" both at a same time. Guess there is nothing left than to write the function myself

Comment: you can now (2014) do <c:if test="${not empty name}">variable name is undefined</c:if>

Answer (score 3):

There are **No built-in functions** to check this in a JSP, so I guess you would have to make one, which I think should be a fairly simple task if you take the bookish meaning of `null`.

If not bookish then `null` is sort of an overloaded term, it could mean any of the following in general usage:

1. actually `null` String, which could throw `NullPointerException`.
2. `""`, empty string which might be called null.
3. `"null"`
4. An acutally `null` array. :-)
5. An empty array.
6. An array with just `null` objects ...

So you can build a method to include these or other cases you can think of for null-check or just the basic-primitive-unembellished null-check.

In Java I suppose there is no such thing as an `undefined` variables, since it is a [statically typed language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2696369/468763) and compiler would catch any of these so called `undefined` errors :-)

In PHP (since I think you took this function from there) you have these things because it is a scripting language and is not a statically typed language like Java.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking against `null`, you can use this snippet:

```
<c:if test="${not name}">variable name is undefined</c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

for checking variable is sent or not use following function

request.getParameterMap().containsKey("variable")

```
if(request.getParameterMap().containsKey("name"))
{
     out.print(request.getParameter("name"));
}
```