# Is it possible to check whether a value has a particular type in Poly ML?

Tags: types, boolean, ml, polyml

In Poly ML, how would you write a function that returned "true" if x was of type 'a, and false if it wasn't?

Comment: What would you use this function for?

Answer (score 1):

I might have misunderstood your question, but it sounds like you have missed the whole point of a [statically typed language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690544/what-is-the-difference-between-a-strongly-typed-language-and-a-statically-typed).

That means you can't call a function with arguments of other types, than what it is declared to. Anything else will be rejected by the interpretor/compiler.

One function that will do what you want is:

```
> fun foo _ = true
val foo = fn : 'a -> bool
```