# Why do you have to specify method return type in Java?

Tags: java, oop, types

Sometimes I see methods declared like this:

```
public MethodName() { ... }
```

other times, I see methods declared with a class defining the type they are returning(?). For example:

```
public ClassName methodName() { ... }
```

What's the point of this? Why do I have to specify the return type?

Comment: Because that's the way the language was designed.

Comment: Java is a **strongly typed** language.

Comment: Don't you mean `public void methodname()`? Because omitting a return type would mean it's a constructor, and the name wouldn't be `methodname()` it would be `Classname()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you always have to specify the method return type. The reason you have to do so is because Java is **strongly and statically typed**, which means that the compiler has to know the types of all expressions during compile time.

What you see what looks like a method with no return type is actually a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) for the class, using it you can create an instance of your class.

Comment: what do you mean by "strongly [...] typed" ?  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690544/what-is-the-difference-between-a-strongly-typed-language-and-a-statically-typed where it is explained: "the word "strong" doesn't really mean anything"

Answer (score 1):

When you have a Constructor, it doesn't have a return type and technically the signature is `<init>(Lpackage.Type;)V` where the `V` would stand for `void`.  It doesn't return an object of the type instead it takes an object of the type and initialises it.

---

At the JVM level, the return type is part of the signature.  Consider this method, if you compile a program using a method like

```
public static long zero() { return 0; }
```

but you later re-compile this method, but not the methods which call it like this.

```
public static int zero() { return 0; }
```

the methods which were compiled with the old code will fail to find the method they were compiled against.  This is because those methods were compiled with the assumption that a `long` was returned and they might not even compile with an `int` being returned.