# Why doesn't PHP allow class variables to be assigned as objects?

Tags: java, php

So I have the following question: Why doesn't PHP allow class variable to be instantiated as objects, this is probably the wrong question so I'll show some code to just clarify what I mean.

In java you can do this

```
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
```

But in PHP if you try to do something similar like the following

```
private $var = \MY_CLASS
```

It will throw a syntax error and you will have to instantiate it through the constructor.
I mean in java you also need to instantiate the variables through the constructor..

Comment: Just a sidenote: Your Java-Snippet does not instantiate, it just declares ...

Comment: @Fildor yes I know that. That's what i say in my last paragraph. I'll edit the  question to "Why doesn't php allow class variables to be assigned as objects?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the interpreters - including the PHP - is a language with a "free-typed data" (loose typed language):

[Strong and weak typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing)
[What is the difference between a strongly typed language and a statically typed language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690544/what-is-the-difference-between-a-strongly-typed-language-and-a-statically-typed)

It's just one of the approaches to the practice of building language translators.

This does not mean that it is bad. It just means that when designing the architecture of your application, you are taking responsibility for control of the correctness of your data.

But how true it was already mentioned, you may use the annotation mechanism for describing what you want to do

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can only add a phpDoc comment for so that the IDE can help you but you can **specify the type (class or array primitive)** as arguments for a method

```
namespace Services;
use Services/SubNamespace/AnotherClass;

class Test
{

    /**
    * @var AnotherClass
    */
    private $property;

    public function __construct(AnotherClass $anotherClass){ ... }
    public function addVars(array $array){ ... } //You must check your php version to make sure it supports array typehint
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could use type hinting comments for your IDE to pickup on, and is just general good practice I feel for PHP code. Here is an example:

```
<?php
class ExampleClass {
  /** @var \MY_CLASS */
  private $var;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->var = new \MY_CLASS();
  }
}
```

As a general rule for Object Orientation, you should favour dependency injection, rather than instantiating a new object in your class. Eg:

```
<?php
class ExampleClass {
  /** @var \MY_CLASS */
  private $var;

  public function __construct(\MY_CLASS $var)
  {
    $this->var = $var;
  }
}

$exampleVar = new \MY_CLASS();
$exampleClass = new ExampleClass($exampleVar);
```

Comment: I think the question he is asking, is why it actually doesn't work rather than a way to get around it.

Comment: Yes @AndreFerraz thats exactly what am asking.