# How to defined OpenFeign Response Object?

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud, openfeign

How to defined OpenFeign Response Object when using SpringCloud ?

There are two regular way to do that :

1、With strong type of java；

2、Return String object Or JSON ( exp: JSONObject);

Comment: I believe that depend on how you gonna use the response.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally a good idea to use "static typing" if you can.
You can see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2696369/971735) that can help you to understand why.