# Java: method return type as array error

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion

```
public ProvinceTerritory[] getProvinceWhoseNameContains(String substring){
    String[] names;
    names = new String[13];
    int j=0;

    for(ProvinceTerritory ptt:provinces){
        if(ptt.getName().contains(substring)){
            String singleName=ptt.getName();
            names[j]= singleName;
            j++;
        }
    }
    return names;  \\this is where the error points to
}
```

Why is the return type giving error even though `ProvinceTerritory` and `names` both are of datatype `arrays`?
`"incompatible types:java.lang.String[] can not be converted to ProvinceTerritory[]"`

Comment: your return type is not a string array it should be public String[] getProvinceWhoseNameContains(String substring). ProvinceTerritory[] is not a String array.

Comment: so if i want to keep the method signature the way it is , like : public ProvinceTerritory[] getProvinceWhoseNameContains(String substring){} then what changes should i make to the body of the method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both array. But they are array of different type. So you cannot pass `String[]` for `ProvinceTeritorry[]`.

change your method's return type

```
public String[] getProvinceWhoseNameContains
```

**Update**

And if you want to return `Provinceteritorry[]` then you can do the following

```
public ProvinceTerritory[] getProvinceWhoseNameContains(String substring){
    ProvinceTerritory[] names = new ProvinceTerritory[13];
    int j=0;

    for(ProvinceTerritory ptt:provinces){
        if(ptt.getName().contains(substring)){
            names[j]= ptt;
            j++;
        }
    }
    return names;  
}
```

Comment: hoow if i dont want to change the methos signature and keep that as ProvinceTeritory[], then how can i return names in this way?

Comment: Then instead of String[] create a Provisioceteritorry[] and return that .. in your loop generate this array instead of getting names

Comment: ok i changed it to the following :    public ProvinceTerritory[] getProvinceWhoseNameContains(String substring){
        ProvinceTerritory[] names;
        names = new ProvinceTerritory[13];

        for(ProvinceTerritory ptt:provinces){
            if(ptt.getName().contains(substring)){
                System.out.println(names.);
                
            }
        }
        return names;  
    } and this one is running but it does not give me the names of the povinces correct and it prints like "[LProvinceTerritory;@13fbf44
" do you know why ?

Comment: sorry i dont know how to add code in the comments .

Comment: yes , public ProvinceTerritory[] getProvinceWhoseNameContains(String substring){ ProvinceTerritory[] names; names = new ProvinceTerritory[13]; for(ProvinceTerritory ptt:provinces){ if(ptt.getName().contains(substring)){ System.out.println(names.); } } return names; } and this one is running but it does not give me the names of the povinces correct and it prints like "[LProvinceTerritory;@13fbf44 "

Comment: yes you will get the array of ProvinceTerritory.. now you can use the element of this array and use getNames to get the names.

Comment: But the issue is as soon as i say return names.getName() it gives me the error since getName() gives me the string since the return type for the method is ProvinceTerritory!!

Comment: Can you update your question with your updated code? that will help me to understand more clearly

Comment: ok im using this now :    public ProvinceTerritory[] getProvinceWhoseNameContains(String substring){
        int j =0;
        ProvinceTerritory[] names;
        names = new ProvinceTerritory[13];

        for(ProvinceTerritory ptt:provinces){
            if(ptt.getName().contains(substring)){
                System.out.println(names.getName());

            }
        }
        return names;  
    }  and the issue now is that it is getting error on the line contains                 System.out.println(names.getName()); saying that "can not find symbol - method getName()"

Comment: And whats the problem you are facing now

Comment: i am having an error on line System.out.println(names.getName());  saying that "can not find symbol - method getName()"

Comment: names is the array .. use ptt.getNames there.. I just edited your code that's why may be you are getting confused

Comment: PERFECT! this is working now thanks alot for helping me :-)

Comment: do you know how can i do it if i need to change the reurn type to the ArrayLits in the method signature? cause it seems that it will be very different than this one ? im trying this --> 
    public ArrayList<ProvinceTerritory> getMoreProvincesWhoseNameContains(String substring){
        ArrayList proNames = new ArrayList<ProvinceTerritory>() ;
        for(int i =0; i <proNames.size(); i++){
            if(proNames.get(i).getName().contains(substring)){

                System.out.println(proNames.get(i).getName());

            } 
        }
        return proNames;
    }

Comment: just use pronames.add(ptt) .. in your last code... I think it will be better if you can go through the basic tutorials of java

Answer (score 2):

Java is a [strongly typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing) language.

You can't specify a return value of `ProvinceTerritory[]`, then return a String[] instead.  They are two different types.

If you're interested, you can learn more about the subject from these threads:

[What are the key aspects of a strongly typed language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121385/what-are-the-key-aspects-of-a-strongly-typed-language)

[What is the difference between a strongly typed language and a statically typed language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690544/what-is-the-difference-between-a-strongly-typed-language-and-a-statically-typed)

Answer (score 0):

string[] and ProvinceTerritory[] are different make sure which type function needs to return.
if ProvinceTerritory is required then create array of objects of ProvinceTerritory and return ProvinceTerritory[] else change your function return type to string[].

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**ProvinceTerritory and String are not of same type** .

Both are from completely different hierarchy.
So,
either change the return type to String[] or create the **"names"** an array of ProvinceTerritory .